# How to rate-limit Apache server on IP basis?

Tags: apache-2.2

I currently have a custom implementation in PHP/mysql that keeps track of web hits and blocks those that exceed a certain rate for the same IP. I.e. if a given source IP hits the server more than X times in the last Y seconds then it will be served a redirect to a predefined location Z and the normal request processing will be aborted.

It works OK, but puts significant stress on MySQL.

So I was wondering if there is a special tool for this available? Maybe an Apache module or some kind of filter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best

- [mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442) (Focused more on reducing DoS exposure)
- [mod_cband](http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband/) (Best featured for 'normal' bandwidth control)

and the rest

- [mod_limitipconn](http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn.html)
- [mod_bw](http://bwmod.sourceforge.net/)
- [mod_bwshare](http://www.topology.org/src/bwshare/README.html)

One more option - mod_qos

Not simple to configure - but powerful.

http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/

Comment: Thanks. mod_evasive seems to only serve 403 responses for blocked addresses, but mod_cband looks promising!

Comment: Note that this answer is a verbatim copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131681/how-can-i-implement-rate-limiting-with-apache-requests-per-second/131685#131685. Don't plagiarize other peoples answers without attribution.

Answer (score 5):

you may be able to do this at a lower level with iptables and bypass apache/mysql all together.... match and forward to another host / port?  i have only dropped:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 6 -j DROP
```

Comment: So anyone can DOS you by filling that little "6 conns per minute" bucket?

Comment: This bucket is per IP, no?