# Rate-limit Apache per IP for a specific page

Tags: apache-2.4, rate-limiting

I would like Apache to redirect to an error page when the number of requests per IP to a specific page (selected with regexp) is above some threshold.

What is the simplest way to do that? What module to use? What are the directives to achieve that result?

Running Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/540743/how-to-rate-limit-apache-server-on-ip-basis

Comment: That makes a lot of documentation to read. If somebody already had to solve this specific need and knows the answer, that would be great.

Comment: That's certainly a case for `mod_security`. I cannot give you a recipe with the redirect, though (simply blocking it after X hits is easy to establish with `mod_security` and `fail2ban`, which is what I do).